# Default modal laravel errorr

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use the default modal in laravel, but it doesn't show up and the error I get is that the component is not imported, but it is.

```
const show = ref(false);

const showModal = () => {
    show.value = true;
};

const closeModal = () => {
    show.value = false;
};


<Modal :show="show" @close="closeModal">
    <p>Test to show modal</p>
</Modal>
```

I tried to make my own modal but it didn't work either, I upgraded my project from laravel 8 to laravel 10, and it worked before, could it be a compatibility error?

Comment: Share the real component code